# How to make an optional value input with **Kwargs

Tags: python

So I've been writing a function that takes 2 parameters X and Y and outputs a bar-graph based on them, and then takes some other parameters (like here: title) and does something with it.

I've tried just simply calling the variable and it doesn't work

So how does one use variables in kwargs? Is this even a question I should be asking or is it simply impossible?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bar(x,y,**stuff):
   plt.barh(x,y)
   for key,value in stuff.items():
        if title != "":
            plt.title(stuff[title])
    return plt.show()
bar(["bob","jeff","Dave"],[1,2,3],title = "People")
```

This returns a NameError

Comment: `stuff` is a dict -- do `stuff.get("title")` to get the `title` kwarg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NameError` exception is because `title` is not defined before the `if` condition `if title != "":`. It seems that you are trying to get the keyword argument called `title` passed via `**stuff`. In that case, since `stuff` is a dictionary, you would want to index `stuff` with the key `title`:

```py
def bar(x,y,**stuff):
    plt.barh(x,y)
    if stuff['title'] != "":
        plt.title(stuff['title'])
    return plt.show()
```